# AndroidMainfest merger error

Tags: android, performance

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'
>
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:8:9-43
>       is also present at [Sample:HomeLockerLib:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-22:19 to override.

Comment: SO isn't really for "do this for me!"-type requests. A simple Bing search would've given you the appropriate action. 

https://www.bing.com/search?q=Attribute+application%40icon+value%3D%28%40mipmap%2Fic_launcher%29+from+AndroidManifest.xml%3A8%3A9-43+is+also+present+at+%5BSample%3AHomeLockerLib%3Aunspecified%5D+AndroidManifest.xml%3A15%3A9-45+value%3D%28%40drawable%2Fic_launcher%29.&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=0-199&sk=&cvid=7D5B7C4AD13C4394A7AD12203F9C00AB  

In the future, please explain what you've already tried. Otherwise you'll get fewer useful answers than hoped for.

Comment: From the error message: `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-22:19 to override.`

Answer (score 1):

Add below line inside application tag of your apps Manifest.xml

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

for eg :

```
<application
    android:name=".ApplicationSubClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    tools:replace="android:icon" > //HERE
```

For more information about this bug refer to [this url.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193679)